# Django Form validate PIL Image as ImageField

Tags: django, django-forms, python-imaging-library

Say I have a model and form that support file uploads:

```
class Foo(Document):
    name = StringField()
    file = FileField()


class FooForm(Form):
    name = CharField()
    file = ImageField()

    def save(self):
        Foo(name=self.cleaned_data['name'], file=self.cleaned_data['file']).save()
```

When POSTing from the actual browser `form.is_valid()` returns `True`, so we can call `save()`

When I go to use `FooForm` to take a `PIL` `Image` (specifically a `<PIL.Image._ImageCrop image mode=RGB size=656x677 at 0x10F6812D8>`), `is_valid()` is `False` because `form.errors` says:

```
load a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.
```

Here's what I'm trying to do to save the form:

```
img = ... our PIL image ...
post = {'name': name}
file = {'file': img}
form = FooForm(post, file)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

See what I'm doing wrong that's causing `is_valid()` to be `False`?

**Edit:** I think this issue is more about coercing `PIL` `Image` to something `BaseForm`'s `files` parameter accepts.

Comment: Why are you bothering to use a form here, rather than simply creating the Foo object directly?

Comment: `FooForm` determines extra data for saving `Foo` by reading other `form.cleaned_data`. Consider it the API for uploading this kind of file to the system. I think the problem is that `PIL Image` isn't valid for saving to `FileField`. Not sure what the conversion process would be. Good question btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being my solution to get the `FooForm` to properly validate. I'm sure there's a better method.

```
img = ... our PIL image ...
buffer = StringIO()
img.save(buffer, 'png')
buffer.seek(0)
image_file = SimpleUploadedFile('foo.png', buffer.read(), content_type="image/png")
buffer.close()
post = {'name': name}
file = {'file': image_file}
form = FooForm(post, file)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing the form initialisation to use a simple dictionary like this:

```
img = ... our PIL image ...
form = FooForm({'name': name, 'file': img})
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

Comment: This just returns form.errors: `u'This field (file) is required.'`. The arguments for BaseForm go `data` (POST), then `files` (FILES). I think the issue is more about converting the `PIL` Image to something `Form` considers an uploaded file.